# PHP Session & Login

Tags: php, arrays, session, variables

I have a login and session creation script for a cms. It checks an admin file for correct details otherwise does a SQL query for user details. A session variable is set depending on which is successful then the according page loaded.

The script works on PHP 5.2 but I've been trying to rewrite the code to fix deprecated functions for PHP 5.4, `register_globals` and `$http_session_vars` in particular. The problem I think I am getting is that the variable `($s_Vers)` is not being set properly as it's utilising an array.

To get around `register_globals`:

```
$aPwd = $_REQUEST['aPwd'];
$aLogin = $_REQUEST['aLogin'];
$lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
$pswd = $_REQUEST['pswd'];
```

This seems to be working fine.

For `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS` I've replaced all instances with `$_SESSION`. I'm going to assume it's not that simple. An extract of the `if` statement that should set `$s_vers` for the admin.

```
if ( $lname === $aLogin
  && (( $aPwd && md5($pswd) === $aPswd )
  || (!$aPswd && $name === $pswd )) )
{ 
$s_Vers  = $_SESSION["s_Vers"] = 0;
$s_aid   = $_SESSION["s_uid"] = 0;
}
```

After this there is an else statement to run an SQL query for the user login details.

Then there is this:

```
else $wrong = true;
}

if( isset($_SESSION["s_Vers"]) && !@$wrong )
{
  include "setup.php";
    if( $s_Vers == 0 )
        header("Location: adminpage.php");
    else
        header("Location: userpage.php");
    exit();
}
```

Is there anything in the above that is glaringly wrong?

The session variables are being stored in the session array which looks like this:

```
session_start();
$session_array = array("username", "password", "s_uid", "s_Vers");
```

So what happens when I enter the admin details is that I see it direct to the adminpage.php as it should then it logs me out. I guess due to this:

```
if ( (!IsSet($curmode) && !$username) || isset($logout)
        || $s_Vers != $_SESSION["s_Vers"] 
        || $s_uid != $_SESSION_["s_uid"]
     )
{
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $curmode = 0;
    session_destroy();
//  echo "Here";
//  exit();
//  Header("Location: http://".$g_AfterLogoutURL);
?>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Not Authorised</TITLE>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=login.php">
    </HEAD>

<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    parent.location="login.php";
</SCRIPT>

    <BODY>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
<?
    exit();
}
```

`s_Vers` is being set as global in two functions that are in a required file, but not executed until the adminpage is loaded.

There's other parts to the script with requires and variable declarations but not related to the session or login sequence.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong, or can provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check `$_SESSION["s_Vers"]` using `var_dump();`, bec. for

```
$s_Vers  = $_SESSION["s_Vers"] = 0;
```

variables should be of **one and the same type**, otherwise `=` operator will not take place.

In your case it should be *(int)*, bec. last item (*which is 0*) is of *(int)* type.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 'var_dump' is not working, I'm not sure of the correct way to implement it to be honest. This scripts works on PHP 5.2 with '$_SESSION' swapped for '$HTTP_SESSION_VARS'. I feel that there's something extra that I need to do..

Comment: @Mikhail, what do you mean under "var_dump is not working"? Regarding `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS` it is for PHP 4.0.6 or less, in later versions `$_SESSION` is used. You've already corrected it.

Comment: @Mikhail, have a look at `!$aPswd && $name === $pswd`, are you sure you have variable `$name` and not `$lname`?

Comment: I think that `$name` was a typo when copying here. The verification works in dev, it returns error message if the wrong details are entered. There is also a sign up form to sign up a regular user, the same problem happens there, when the form is submitted it refreshes the page instead of submitting. Re: `var_dump` I have put `<? var_dump($s_Vers); ?>` after the form and it shows nothing when opening the page.

Comment: @Mikhail, are you sure short tags (`<? ?>`) are enabled?